# Dom-storage: необходимое API

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-7, реестр, c++

Добрый день, дорогие форумчане!

Прошу вас сориентировать меня в вопросе по поводу Dom-storage. Гуглила, но особо ничего интересного не нашла. На сколько я поняла, это некое подобие журнала истории Internet Explorer, который хранится в реестре. Однако, не понятно, какая именно информация о посещённой странице там хранится, кроме URL. Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за зверь такой, Dom-storage. Точнее, необходимое API, которое будет работать с данным объектом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, судя по богатым ответам, накопившимся здесь, придётся прояснить всё-таки данный вопрос.
Из того, что я обнаружила, я поняла, что можно работать с реестром с помощью специальных функций. Конкретно, для работы с реестром понадобится знание того, что такое HKEY, затем, как осуществлять поиск в реестре и сбор значения ключей.
Вот тут как раз есть функции для работы с реестром:
[Registry Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx). Его можно открывать, брать/задавать значения узлов, копировать узлы, удалять, осуществлять поиск. Удачи тому, кому это пригодится.

P.S.: А здесь (если вы ещё этого не нашли) хорошо структурированная информация о реестре: [About the Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724182(v=vs.85).aspx)